# Image looks blurry after start of the app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, uisplitviewcontroller

I use an image with some buttons on it in my iPad split view app. When the app starts in portrait mode, the image looks a bit blurry. When I rotate it to landscape and back to portrait, it looks crisp.

Why?

Comment: maybe the bounds of the UIImageView change to a size larger than the image, hence pixelating it?

Answer (score 1):

Your UIImageView has certainly an autoresizingMask that make it being placed at, for example, 0.5;0.5, or being resized so that your image is scaled.

In interface builder, under the Size Inspector (ruller icon), try tweaking parameters to get the effect you want